# How is the EndpointSlice improve efficiency over the old Endpoint resource?

Tags: kubernetes

The original Endpoint had one resource per Service and all the endpoints (ports) of a service were tracked by this resource. This caused issues with scalability as the cluster and services grew.

With the new EndpointSlice, there is an EndpointSlice resource per endpoint per service. I am wondering how does this solve the scalability issue? Each pod in a service supports all the ports (endpoints) opened by the service. That said, won’t each pod find a reference entry in each of the endpointSlice related to that service? Will that not require simultaneous update of multiple EndpointSlice resources every time there is a change in the pod (new addition or deletion)?

Example: Say there is a Service A. It has got 3 pods P1, P2, P3. The Service A has 3 open ports (endpoints). Now each of the pods support these endpoints. So if we are to create one EndpointSlice resource per service, per endpoint (port), then we will have 3 EndpointSlice resources ES1, ES2 and ES3 for the Service A corresponding to each of its endpoints.
Now since each of the pods P1, P2and P3 support all 3 endpoints each of the EndpointSlice ES1, ES2 and ES3 will have a reference to each of the pod’s IP address and port. So in case there is a newly adde pod (with new IP address ofcourse) oran existing pod gets replaces, would these events not require update of all 3 endpoint slice resources? Will this not be more work than before?
How does this improve scalability exactly?

Answer (score 4):

Per service there is only one `endpointslice` object. So in your example there will be only one `endpointslice` object which will have all the 3 pod ip and port and it will group network `endpoints` together by unique `service` and `port` combinations.

Read more [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/community/blob/master/sig-scalability/blogs/k8s-services-scalability-issues.md#endpoints-traffic-is-quadratic-in-the-number-of-endpoints) about what kind of issues the earlier endpoint object faced.

The [official KEP](https://github.com/kubernetes/enhancements/tree/master/keps/sig-network/20190603-endpointslices#estimation) talks about the some performance comparison between endpoints and endpointslice api.

The previous endpoints objects looks like

```
Subsets:
  Addresses:          192.168.238.108,192.168.238.109,192.168.238.110
```

As you can see endpoints object for a service contains all the individual endpoints of that service. As a result, whenever even a single pod in a service is added/updated/deleted, the whole endpoints object (which includes even the other endpoints that didn't change) is re-computed, written to storage and sent to all readers.

New endpoint slice object looks like

```
Ports:
  Name             Port  Protocol
  ----             ----  --------
  http-queueadm    8022  TCP
  http-autometric  9090  TCP
  http-usermetric  9091  TCP
  http             8012  TCP
Endpoints:
  - Addresses:  192.168.238.108
    Conditions:
      Ready:    true
    Hostname:   <unset>
    TargetRef:  Pod/helloworld-go-rk4j8-deployment-588ccc679b-4spkx
    Topology:   kubernetes.io/hostname=ip-10-0-0-92
  - Addresses:  192.168.238.110
    Conditions:
      Ready:    true
    Hostname:   <unset>
    TargetRef:  Pod/helloworld-go-rk4j8-deployment-588ccc679b-tdq24
    Topology:   kubernetes.io/hostname=ip-10-0-0-92
  - Addresses:  192.168.238.109
    Conditions:
      Ready:    true
    Hostname:   <unset>
    TargetRef:  Pod/helloworld-go-rk4j8-deployment-588ccc679b-bfxb8
    Topology:   kubernetes.io/hostname=ip-10-0-0-92
```

As you can see the endpoints are grouped and so when there is change i.e a single pod in a service is added/updated/deleted only relevant group can be updated rather than updating the entire object which improves the performance.